# Neural Network to output the forecast and its probability

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

Is there a way to train neural network to output two values - the forecast, and its probability?

Example: let's say we want to predict time series `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ?`, we want to know two numbers - the forecast itself and its probability - how sure the Neural Net about its prediction (in this case it could be two numbers `6` and `90%`).

Do you know if that's possible? And any reference to docs / examples of Neural Net that does that or something similar?

**Note**: the predicted value is not categorical / class, it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what library are you using for training neural networks but usually they are able to produce both the predicted probability and the predicted class.

Take `keras` as an example, the trained model has the following two methods:

1. `predict_proba`: predict the output class probabilities
2. `predict_classes`: predict the output class index

Usually (2) is (1) with a threshold value of 0.5. You can call both of them to get the two output predictions or you can call (1) and then set custom thresholds as well.

Comment: For class - yes - it will output kinda probabilities of each class. But how to do it for numerical output? When the predicted value is not a class but a number.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Ah, I see. I personally think that's a difficult task and there isn't much research about that, and I don't think those are implemented in current deep learning packages. However, you should be able to find a number of research papers about how such interval (or band) can be calculated. Here's something I found: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.520.9288&rep=rep1&type=pdf